# В коде на php ошибка и не пойму в чем

Tags: php, yii2

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in Z:\domains\utverdil\1484627257_account_u0270056_u0270056_16.01.2017\u0270056\data\www\utverdil.ru\index.php on line 12.

В чем ошибка? Никак не могу понять. 12 строка это последняя.

Comment: норм там бекапы в открытом доступе лежат у вас)

Answer (score 3):

```
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Ваша версия php не позволяет подобных выражений.

Обновите php, или
Разбейте строку на 2:

```
$app = new yii\web\Application($config);
$app->run();
```

или мы в одном проекте на php5.3 использовали глобальную функцию(имя подберите сами):

```
function f($a) {return $a;}
```

Тогда можно:

```
f(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: такой вопрос, что если я это делаю на локальном хостинге? как указать версию?

Comment: Что значит указать? Нужно установить нужную версию. Посмотреть можно либо в cli: `php --version` либо в браузере смотреть вывод функции `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 3):

Вы используете [yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2).

Yii2 требует PHP не ниже 5.4. А у вас, видимо, PHP 5.3 или ниже.

Предложенные ответы, где вам предлагают изменить вызов `->run()` не помогут, потому что в Yii2 везде используется синтаксис PHP 5.4. Даже если вы исправите вызов в этой строке, ошибки будут появляться в других местах.

Вам нужно обновить версию PHP на вашем компьютере. Как это сделать зависит от того, какой пакет вы использовали для установки веб-сервера на компьютер.

Answer (score 2):

В php ранее 5.4 версии Необходимо сначала создать объект

```
$test = new yii\web\Application($config);
$test->run()
```